# Logging c gives segafult sometimes

Tags: c

AM creating a logfile in my application . The application writes data into the logifile and rotates(old to be deleted new to be added) whenver the size reaches to 10 MB.

```
This works fine ,but sometime it gives segafult.
The code for the same 

/* when the application starts the new file got created on the path*/
    char path[1024];
    char logpath[1024];
    char logfile_name[20] = "test";
    getcwd(path,1024);
    sprintf(logpath,"%s/TEST_LOGS/%s_%d_%d.log",path,logfile_name,
        app_inst_id,getpid());
     /
    logfptr = fopen(logpath,"a");
    if(logfptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("log file open failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
```

logfile created initially

```
int vlr_write_log(const char *format, va_list A)
{     
     struct stat st;
     char path[1024];
     char logpath[1024];
     char logfile_name[20] = "test";
     getcwd(path,1024);
     sprintf(logpath,"%s/TEST_LOGS/%s_%d_%d.log",path,logfile_name,
         app_inst_id,getpid());
     int size_in_byte = 10*1024*1024;
     if (logfptr!=NULL)
     {
         if( stat(logpath,&st) == 0)
         {
         /******* if file size is less than 10MB
                  append it to the log file also 
                  open it in write mode  *******/

             if( st.st_size < size_in_byte)
             {
                 vfprintf(logfptr,format,A);
             }
             else
             {
                 fflush(logfptr);
                 if(logfptr!= NULL)
                     fclose(logfptr);   // this gives the error 
                 logfptr = NULL;
                 logfptr = fopen(logpath,"w");
                 vfprintf(logfptr,format,A);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             if(logfptr!= NULL)
                 fclose(logfptr);
             logfptr = NULL;
             logfptr = fopen(logpath,"w");
             vfprintf(logfptr, format, A);
             fflush(logfptr);
         }
     }

     return 0;
}
```

and the backtrace for the same

```
#0  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
   #1  0x0036fe30 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
   #2  0x00371741 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
   #3  0x003a88cb in __libc_message () from /lib/libc.so.6
   #4  0x003b0c65 in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
   #5  0x003b4c59 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
   #6  0x0039f2d6 in fclose@@GLIBC_2.1 () from /lib/libc.so.6
   #7  0x08049aa7 in vlr_write_log (format=0xff99525c "[2014-01-10 17:06:13.416] key =       input_list:LM1561171389353710\n", A=0xff995374 "\340\\\231\377 \004"
```

)

Thanks
Saroj

Comment: I'm not sure you understand log _rotation._ You're supposed to save off the old log somewhere before obliterating it with another `open("w")`.

Comment: I dont want to save the old log .Need to overwrite the log.

Comment: Rename the old log to '.bak', open the new log, then delete the old one if you have to.

Comment: Please indent your code, I can hardly read it.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, you've clearly overwritten something on the heap. What and where is unclear, though it doesn't immediately appear to be in your logging code as that doesn't access the heap. (Although it's quite difficult given your one-size-fits-all indenting).

as an aside, this:

```
char path[1024];
char logpath[1024];
getcwd(path,1024);
sprintf(logpath,"%s/TEST_LOGS/%s_%d_%d.log",path,logfile_name,app_inst_id,getpid());
```

could be coded rather more safely as:

```
char path[1024];
char logpath[1024];
getcwd(path, sizeof(path));
snprintf(logpath, sizeof(logpath), "%s/TEST_LOGS/%s_%d_%d.log", path, logfile_name, app_inst_id, getpid());
```

in case your path is a little on the big size, and you *really* should test the return codes of getcwd and snprintf